# Do form select options need to be individual models in a REst API?

Tags: php, laravel, rest

Let´s say my application sells boxes, so my basic model it's a box.

However, I will have a form, which will have select options for each box characteristics (e.g. box color, box dimensions, box material, etc.).

These options will be resources returned from my API.

For this reason I was wondering if they have to be individual models too in the MVC world. For example, to fetch the form options for box colors, does it make sense to have a specific endpoint like http://example.test/api/box-colors, and so on?

My idea was that all these characteristics would be under a same model and could be returned from one end point. What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different tables as you mentioned for box_colors, box_dimensions, box_materials etc. However, these values are going to change very rarely I suppose. You can combine these into one table then :

Table : `box_options` :

- `id` : primary key, auto increment
- `type` : string or enum, values can be `box_color`, `box_dimension` etc
- `value` : string, value of the specified type.

For example, if you want to store 2 box colors and 2 box dimensions :

```
|id   |type         |value   |
|_____|_____________|________|
|1    |box_color    | red    |
|2    |box_color    | blue   |
|3    |box_dimension| 50X50  |
|4    |box_dimension| 70X70  |
```

In your eloquent model :

```
<?php 

Class BoxOption extends Model{

    protected $table = 'box_options';

    const BOX_COLOR_TYPE = 'box_color';
    const BOX_DIMENSION_TYPE = 'box_dimension';
    const BOX_MATERIAL_TYPE = 'box_meterial';

    public function scopeColor($query){

        return $query->where('type', self::BOX_COLOR_TYPE);
    }

    public function scopeDimension($query){

        return $query->where('type', self::BOX_DIMENSION_TYPE);
    }

    public function scopeMaterial($query){

        return $query->where('type', self::BOX_MATERIAL_TYPE);
    }
}
```

And then you can get these easily :

```
<?php 

$colors = BoxOption::color()->get()->pluck('value');
$dimensions = BoxOption::dimension()->get()->pluck('value');
$materials = BoxOption::material()->get()->pluck('value');
```

Comment: I can see that you're going towards having all these options under the same model as I thought. However, how this could be done without having to have all the options in one table? My option tables are going to be large and I'd like to have them separate.

Comment: If you are having very large options, then having separate tables is the good option. However, as your options increase, the number of tables also increase. Personally I would not mind having large set of options in one table to keep the hierarchy simple.